# Nested for loops but with a twist

Tags: java

So recently I am having trouble understanding nested for loops. For example, one question asks: The following nested loop structure will execute the inner most statement (x++) how many times?

```
for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
{
    for (int k = 100; k > 0; k--)
    {
        x++;
    }
}
```

Can you keep it in simple terms, as I am fairly new to programming? Thanks!

Comment: How many times with the inner loop be done? Now how many times will you repeat the inner loop (or, how many times will you go through the outer loop)? Multiply those two numbers together, that's your answer.

Comment: Just print `x` value after both for loops. You will get an answer.

Comment: One loop is counting up; the other one is counting down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every inner loop, the for loop will execute `x++` 100 times. You will also run the inner for loop 100 times. So in total you will run `x++` 100 x 100 = 10000 times.

Comment: But what I don't get is there is a j++, then a k--. That's what's throwing me off.

Comment: The first loop starts from 0 and ends at 100. The inner loop starts at 100 and ends at 0. It's just reversed.

Comment: Inner loop is counting down 100 times for each iteration of the outer loop. So there are 100 iteration for the outer loop, hence it's `100 X 100=10000`

Comment: That is just the condition to break the loop, j starts from 0 and it loops until it reach 99 (100 times of looping), on the other hand k starts from 100 and loops until it reach 1 (100 times). It goes like this:
First loop: i =0, K =100 (inner loop k--)
Second loop i=0, K=99 (inner loop k--)
....
100th loop i=0, K=1 (inner k--) (at this point it breaks out of the inner loop)
101st loop i=1, k=100 (outer loop i++) (back to inner loop K=100)

Answer (score 1):

For each j, the k loop executes a 100 times hence incrementing x by 100. See illustration below:

> for j=**0**; k=100, k=99, k=98 .... k=2, k=1; x is now 100
>
> for j=**1**; k=100, k=99, k=98 .... k=2, k=1; x is now 200
>
> .............................................
>
> .............................................
>
> for j=**98**; k=100, k=99, k=98 .... k=2, k=1; x is now 9900
>
> for j=**99**; k=100, k=99, k=98 .... k=2, k=1; x is now 10000

The result would have been the same, had the code been modified as:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    for(int k = 0; k < 100; k++) // NOTE: reversal of k here.
    {
        x++;
    } 
}
```

The inner k loop is just being executed in reverse order (from 100 to 0) just to confuse the newbies.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++)     //j -> 0~99 =>total=100
{
    for(int k = 100; k > 0; k--) //k -> 100~1 =>total=1oo
    {
       x++;
    }
}

System.out.println(x);           //should print 10000 bcz of 100*100
```

Comment: Please add explanatory text to your answer and don't just post code. This will help others to learn from their mistakes instead of just copying a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to understand how many times each loop executes.

Note that first loop runs 100 times. So, everything inside it will repeat 100 times. The inner loop also runs 100 times. So `x++` will execute 100 * 100 = 10000 times.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)      // 100 times
{
    for (int k = 100; k > 0; k--)  // 100 * 100 times
    {
        x++;                       // 100 * 100 times
    }
}

System.out.println("x = " + x);    // This should print 10000 (assuming that x is zero initially)
```